# BootableUSB Stick created for installation, doesn't working on Ubuntu13.04

Tags: boot, usb, system-installation, live-usb, bootloader

I also Download a ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso file and also created a live USB stick by Startup disk creator. It's status said, Live USB disk creation complete. Then I did restart but nothing happen. It's not booting. How I can install it. Please help me.
I'm using ubuntu 13.04.
Motherboard: Gigabyte G-41MT-ES2L

Comment: Did you change the boot order in bios?

Comment: Hey, Ferit Cubukcuoglu, thanks for your answer, I also did it by your answer, but It didn't work yet.

Comment: what appears on the screen while you boot from USB?

Comment: When I started to boot from USB then screen apears "boot from CD/DVD..." & then Ubuntu 13.04 normally starts. I also made first boot prioty- USB HDD than hardisk from bios, then tried- first boot device-USB FDD from boot menu. But NOthing happen.

Answer (score 1):

You must set the usb stick boot priority higher than the hard disk. 
You can do this thing in bios.